# How to parse these lines? awk? perl?

Tags: shell, parsing

I've got mail.log lines involving postgrey that I want to pull variables from to do my own custom reports (I'm not a fan of postgreyreport). The lines look like this:

```
Jul 15 01:08:50 mail postgrey[14184]: action=pass, reason=triplet found, delay=511, client_name=a0i108.smtpcorp.com, client_address=64.131.95.193, sender=xx@xx, recipient=xx@xx
Jul 17 00:10:53 mail postgrey[3953]: action=greylist, reason=new, client_name=outbound.na.e.paypal.com, client_address=96.47.30.204, sender=0687VFT-RNOEGR-FXQOI6-XTJG5DO-OF2K7B-H-M2-20140717-d0a7662385177@na.e.paypal.com, recipient=xx@xx
```

I want to basically read all the lines matching `postgrey.*action=` and pull the fields into variables, e.g. `action=$1, reason=$2` and then use those variables to print my own custom report or log. An even bigger bonus would be to not dump out lines that have already been dumped before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never thought I'd have to write this comment for an OP with >1000 rep, but ... "Please post the code you've tried so far and what didn't work."

Comment: Maybe there *is* no code because I have absolutely no idea where to start.

Comment: How would the tool know which records have been dumped before? I would probably use Perl for this, but I know Perl better than I know Python. I'd probably not use `awk`; it would be a little more awkward to handle the `key=value` notation in `awk` than in Perl.  You've not shown anything of the format you want the output to appear in. I'd probably use splitting to handle the lines, and then use regexes to analyze the `key=value` fields. You'd need to research the conventions used; it appears that after the `postgrey[number]:` field, the entries are comma separated rather than space separated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (my $line = <STDIN>)
{
  if ($line =~ /postgrey\[\d+\]: action=(.*), reason=(.*?),.* client_name=(\S+), client_address=(\S+), sender=(\S+), recipient=(\S+)/)
  {
    print "Action: $1\n";
    print "Reason: $2\n";
    print "Client: $3 ($4)\n";
    print "From: $5\n";
    print "To: $6\n\n";
  }
}
```